# using python reserved keyword as variable name

Tags: python, django, web-services, python-3.x

im trying to send sms using  a webservice , this is  what webservice document suggest  :

```
response = client.service.SendSMS(  fromNum = '09999999' ,
                toNum = '0666666666666',
                messageContent = 'test',
                messageType = 'normal',
                user = 'myusername',
                pass = '123456' ,
           )
```

to be fair they dont have document for python only php/asp so i've converted this from their php sample but as unlike me some may know `pass` is a reserved keyword of python

so i cant have variable name `pass` becuz i get syntax error !

is there a way around trhis or i should switch to another webservice ? i wish we could put variable names in quotation  mark or something

Comment: Maybe the argument should be a dictionary, not separate parameters?

Comment: They have a Python API, but no detailed documentation for how to use it?

Comment: From the docs https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords. Reserved words **cannot** be used as ordinary identifiers

Comment: @Barmar no python is not very popular where i am , so they dont have doc at all !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass in arbitrary strings as keyword arguments using the `**dictionary` call syntax:

```
response = client.service.SendSMS(  fromNum = '09999999' ,
                toNum = '0666666666666',
                messageContent = 'test',
                messageType = 'normal',
                user = 'myusername',
                **{'pass': '123456'}
           )
```

You can move all the keyword arguments into a dictionary if you want to, and assign that dictionary to a variable before applying.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe try it like this:

```
sms_kwargs = {
    'toNum': '0666666666666',
    'messageContent': 'test',
    'messageType': 'normal',
    'user': 'myusername',
    'pass': '123456'
}
response = client.service.SendSMS(**sms_kwargs)
```